# Merging an ancestor commit of a branch back to HEAD

Tags: git

I have a commit history like this. The actual repo I am planning to apply the solution is much bigger. Nonetheless, it looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do, in simple terms, is to merge `experiment` to the `master` branch. The idea is to do a `reset` without losing my commits in the `master` branch. I am not using `revert` since in the actual repo, the amount of commits between `master` and `experiment` is many more than the image above. Once the `merge` is done, I simply want to see changes in the `experiment` only: So the working directory would look like after how the following command would be executed: `git checkout master; git reset --hard experiment` in `master` branch.

Since the `experiment` branch is already in the history of the `master` branch, I am getting a notification `"Already up to date."` when I run the following commands:

```
git checkout master
git merge experiment -X theirs --squash
```

I tried the `merge` option but I am open to alternative approaches as long as it accomplishes what I need. I appreciate all the answers.

### Update #1 based on Kaz's answer:

Kaz's answer is good but seems missing a critical piece. The following image shows the evolution of the history after I used his/her suggested answer:

[image]

As you see that the final `commit` does not change the `master` but creates a detached commit.

The solution is to convert it to a branch and merge that branch back to `master` as shown below:

[image]

Comment: So what aspect of **actually** doing `git checkout master; git reset --hard experiment` is not right? Just that it's a non-fast-forward change?

Comment: @Kaz Right, that would lose the commits that lead to f386ada. What you can do is `git commit-tree experiment^{tree} -p HEAD -m "Reset to experiment"` and then `git merge` the resulting commit. This creates a bulk revert.

Comment: Even simpler: `git checkout experiment; git reset master`.  Now your working tree/index looks like `experiment`, but you're on `master`. You can commit that to make `master` look like `experiment`.

Comment: What’s wrong with a fast forward merge?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Probably that it's not working because the baseline to be m erged is already an ancestor of the target branch; they are already merged.

Comment: @Kaz You can still merge experiment into master. They don’t point to the same commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way to make a branch look like some old version of itself in one fell swoop is this:

Here, we assume we are starting on `master`; if not, then `git checkout master` is required first:

```
git tag starting-point                 # save our current location
git reset --hard old-commit-on-master  # hard-reset master to old commit
git reset --soft master starting-point # soft-reset master back to start
git tag -d starting-point              # optional: tidy up
```

Now your working tree + index look like `old-commit-on-master`, but you're on `master`. All of the changes to make `master` look like `old-commit-on-master` are staged—you can check that with `git diff --cached`. All that is left to do is:

```
git commit
```

And, perhaps you may want to clean away the `starting-point` tag:

```
git tag -d starting-point
```

This works because the first `git reset --hard` makes the working tree look like `old-commit-on-master`, while we stay on `master`, because we have actually moved `master` to that commit.  Then, the second `git reset`, because it specifies `--soft`, preserves the tree while moving the `master` ref back to where it was. So as far as Git is history is concerned, nothing has changed. Very simple, understandable from the `git reset` man page.

This is not a merge, though; it has only one parent: the previous `master` commit.  I would put into the commit comment that it's a revert of everything since `old-commit-on-master` to the immediate parent.

Note: I've not tested this with a situation that would require files to be added or removed. Hopefully they get properly staged.

Note that if you use `git reset` instead of `git reset --soft`, you get the default `--mixed`, with different results. The changes won't be staged, but appear as unstaged differences against the `master` `HEAD`. I suspect that might not handle file additions without manual `git add` intervention.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I never thought about forward `reset` actually. I will check if there is any answer using/closer-to `merge` command, and if not, this is an answer I could accept.

Comment: It seems that your answer is missing a critical piece. Please check out my updated question above!

Comment: Are you kidding? The missing piece is that the revision was hanging on _detached HEAD_? Just set a branch right there with `git branch blah` or `git branch -f master`.

Comment: @Tarik Ah, you're right of course. If we checkout `old-commit-on-master`, we have of course left `master` behind. We will get the right picture, but it's not installed as the `master` branch; we will have to force `master` to point to it.

Comment: I think we could do it like this: starting on `master`:  `git reset --hard old-commit;  git reset <previous-sha-of-master>`.  I.e. move `master back to the old commit, and then sof/mixed reset back to the original location.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want to do is have a 5th revision for master that has the exact same content as second, this is the way to go:

```
git checkout --detach experiment # checkout second revision, no branch
git reset --soft master
git commit -m "Going back to how things where in second"
# if you like the result
git branch -f master # set master over here
git checkout master # start working on master, again
```